# Card game for iPhone with multiplayer over wifi or game center?

Tags: iphone, ios, multiplayer

I started with creating a card game for iOS and I'm interested whether or not could I create multiplayer over GameCenter or only over WiFi?

Comment: A lot apps work through Game Center, so I don't see why yours couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game Center is an Apple-provided interface for connecting players. Wi-fi is an internet connection method. You can use Wi-Fi to connect to other players anywhere in the world, *through* Game Center.

If you were looking for information on how to create a game *with* Game Center, I would check out  http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12.

If you need information on how to create a multiplayer card game, I would look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/14618/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-intro-and-challenge

Comment: I didin't know how to spell question but I'm interested if I can creare card game to play over game center with other players anywhere in the world in real time.

Comment: yes you can, the second tutorial will show you how to make a card game, the first will show you how to use Game Center